# Using Apple Touch ID in IOS app

Tags: ios

I am currently working on a mobile application for (ios), which has the requirement of collecting user bio metric data. Please tell me whether I can use the inbuilt finger print reader on latest smart phone, tablet to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fingerprint reader on iOS devices can only return a yes/no that indicates whether the finger presented matched a fingerprint enrolled on the device.

Actual fingerprint data is stored securely in the hardware and is not available to the operating system or apps.

So, the short answer to your question is "No" on iOS.

From the iOS Security Guide